# AVPlayer stops playing when screen is unlocked (but works when locked)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to have my AVPlayer play audio in the background, even when the screen is locked. Right now, it does play when the screen is locked, but as soon as it is unlocked, it stops.

In the application delegate I have

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

and I play the sound by doing

```
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:self.mp3URL];
_audioPlayer = player;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[_audioPlayer currentItem]];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

I also have the required background modes set to "App plays audio" in the info.plist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing i see as a reason in the code you posted. perhaps you are reactivating the audio session causing it to stop when the view shows? The error is not in the code you posted.